# Partially match & merge lines

Tags: bash, awk

I want to partially match lines based on the first field & merge the second field from those that match.

Example of input

```
Hello:World
Hell0:World2
Helllo:World1
Hel:world4
```

if I were to match based on the first 4 characters, then the expected output would be

```
Hello:World,World2,World1
Hell0:World2,World,World1
Helllo:World1,World,World2
```

but I was also wondering if it's possible to match percentage based rather than a set number of characters? So match based on `90%` of the string rather than the first `4` characters.

Comment: Of course it is possible, it is just a small matter of programming! What is needed is a more precise definition of the problem. For your example you seem to be using `:` to separate the input line into 2 parts. So is 90% to mean 90% of the length of the first part? If you had this 90% rule would you get another line of output `Hel:World4,World,World2,World1`? Does the order of the worlds matter in the output?

Comment: I mean 90% of the first field, the matching field. The order of field2 doesn't matter

Comment: What does `90% of the first field` mean? 90% of common characters (if so unique or not?), or a substring that's 90% of the length? Case-sensitive or not? With start/end anchors or not? As a regexp or string match? As of now there's a dozen different things you could be trying to do that aren't stated in your question nor covered by your example. Please [edit] your question to fix that so we can help you.

Comment: To be honest, the "90% match" sounds like you actually want an [*approximate string matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) amongst the keys, and then return all the values that belong to the matching keys. Is that true?

Comment: A couple of cases. First if you have a rule of 90%, and two input lines of "helloworlX:foo" and "helloworlYhelloworld:bar" are you expecting the output to be 2 lines "helloworlX:foo,bar" and "helloworlYhelloworld:bar" because 90% of "helloworlX" is "helloworl" and that matches the first 9 characters of "helloworlYhelloworld" but 90% of "helloworlYhelloworld" is "helloworlYhellowor" and that doesn't match the start of "helloworlX".  In other words you are not partitioning the lines into equivalency classes (if A equals B and B equals C then this doesn't imply A equals C).

Comment: What about changing the X and Y to `d`? The first 10 characters of helloworldhelloworld do match but not the first 90% (18 characters). Your 'Hel:' example seems to support this second case.

Comment: For each line L, identify a 90% prefix of the key. Then find all other lines M whose key has that prefix, and merge the values from every M into L.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in TXR Lisp:

```
$ txr soln.tl < data   # 70% hard-coded in program
Hello:World,World2,World1
Hell0:World2,World,World1
Helllo:World1,World,World2
Hel:world4
```

Code:

```
(defvarl %pct% 70)

(defstruct item ()
  key         ;; original key
  eff-key     ;; %pct% percentage of original key
  value       ;; original value
  value-vec  ;; list headed by original, plus others from other items.

  (:postinit (me)
    ;; Initialize eff-key by taking percentage of key.
    (let* ((len (len me.key))
           (pct-len (trunc (+ (* len %pct%) 50) 100)))
      (set me.eff-key (take pct-len me.key)))
    ;; Initialize value list with original value.
    (set me.value-vec (vec me.value))))

(let* ((items (keep-matches (`@key:@value` (get-lines))
                (new item key key value value)))
       (hash [group-by .eff-key items]))
  ;; iterate over all groups of items that have same eff-key
  (dohash (eff-key group-items hash)
    ;; In each group, iterate over all pairs of items (product).
    (each-prod ((i group-items)
                (j group-items))
      ;; For each pair that isn't an item with itself, augment
      ;; the list, by pushing the other item's value onto value-vec.
      (unless (eq i j)
        (vec-push i.value-vec j.value))))
  ;; Produce output
  (each ((i items))
    (put-line `@{i.key}:@{i.value-vec ","}`)))
```

The `Hel` item is not removed; it's not clear what the criteria for that are.

For instance we could cull those items that belong to a group of size 1 (no other items share the same effective key).

Since those items end up with a `value-vec` of length 1, a way to cull them would be to print those items that have two or more entries in the vector:

```
 ;; Produce output
  (each ((i items))
    (if (>= (len i.value-vec) 2)
      (put-line `@{i.key}:@{i.value-vec ","}`)))
```